# How to keep user logged in with AngularFire?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I using angularfire on my app, and I can get the user to login, and I can use the $getAuth() function to check if the user is authenticated. It all works fine until the user closes the browser and comes back to my website. Is it possible to keep the user logged in after he closes the browser?

Comment: Firebase persists the user session to local storage. If the user reloads the page, he will automatically be authenticated again. If you're having trouble making this work, show a [minimal example that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).